# I use Mac. my import numpy was working fine until I tried to install opencv on to my system

Tags: python, numpy

while installing opencv in did that ln -s command and now numpy module is not working if i try to install numpy it shows this

$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/deepakpatel/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.15.0)

but when i try to import that module in python programs its not working it shows this

> > > import numpy
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

so i need some help with this guys 
if you need more info just comment down below

Comment: are you running your program using python3.6?

Comment: yes python 3.6.5

Comment: are you using some environment? What do you get if you do `which python` just before running your script?